# Socket connection doesn't time out

Tags: java, sockets, timeout

I'am trying to set a timeout when a client try to connect to a server, if the server is down, the connection will wait 10 sec befor throwing the timeout exception.
In my case the code bellow throw the IOException without waiting, I really don't get it !

```
public boolean establishConnection()
{
    System.out.println ("Connecting to " +
            this.getServerHostname() + " au port " + this.getServerPort()+ " ...");

    try {

        SocketAddress sockaddr= new InetSocketAddress(_serverHostname, _serverPort);
        _echoSocket = new Socket();
        _echoSocket.connect(sockaddr,10000);
        return _echoSocket.isConnected();


    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Unknown Host: " + this.getServerHostname());
        return false;
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        System.err.println("Timeout");
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException  : " + 
                this.getServerHostname() + ":" + this.getServerPort());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: And the exception you get is .... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll only get a timeout if your connection request is not answered. If the server immediately rejects it, or if the server doesn't exist, you'll get an exception immediately.

Comment: If the server doesn't exist, it there any way in the socket's API to set a time out ? Or I have to go with a Java timer

Comment: I don't understand: if your program knows right away that the connection failed, why would you want to set a timeout?  But sure, you could just call `Thread.sleep()` to wait for ten seconds -- no need to use anything as complicated as a `Timer`.

Answer (score 0):

But is this what you want to achieve?
If your intention is, in case the server is temporarily down, then try again after 10 sec then your approach is wrong.
You should try to do a connection to the server and if you get an exception because the server is down, you can `sleep` for 10 seconds and try the request again.
Otherwise Ernest's answer is correct